# convert data from multiple rows into a single cell

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple frames from which object is detected and detected data is written to a csv. I want to convert data from multiple rows into single cells

I have made the script for object detection and written the detected output to a csv file. Now i want to modify the same

```
    objects = []
    z = 0
    sno=0
    with open(out+'/metadata.csv','a') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['Sr_No','File_Name', 'Object_Detected','Probability']
        #writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        file_is_empty = os.stat(out+'/metadata.csv').st_size == 0
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if file_is_empty:
                writer.writeheader()
        print(Image_Name)
        for index, value in enumerate(classes[0]):
            sno=sno+1
            object_dict = {}
            #writer.writerow([Image_Name])
            if scores[0, index] > threshold:
                object_dict[(category_index.get(value)).get('name')] = scores[0, index]
                objects.append(object_dict)
            while (z<len(objects)):
                    writer.writerow({'Sr_No':sno,'File_Name':Image_Name,'Object_Detected':list(objects[z].keys())[0],'Probability':list(objects[z].values())[0]})
                    print((objects[z]))
                    z=z+1
       # writer.writerow(objects)
```

Actual output

```
Sr_No   File_Name   Object_Detected Probability

1   tiger_23sec_f0.jpg  tiger   0.9975079

2   tiger_23sec_f0.jpg  vehicle 0.90277094

1   tiger_23sec_f1.jpg  tiger   0.9964898

2   tiger_23sec_f1.jpg  vehicle 0.9105579
```

Desired output

```
Sr_No   File_Name   Object_Detected Probability

1   tiger_23sec_f0.jpg  tiger,vehicle   0.9975079,0.90277094

2   tiger_23sec_f1.jpg  tiger,vehicle   0.9964898,0.9105579
```

Comment: This is confusing because we actually would expect `1, 2` and `1, 2` in the `Sr_No` column, from what you've done to the other columns. Please check that this is exactly the output you want, and if it is please give more details about what the rule is to get this.

Comment: @Ashargin Hi....well initially the objects detected from the same frames were written in different rows. Hence the combination 1,2 and 1,2 for the objects detected from same frame in Actual Output. But now i want to put the objects detected from the same frame in 1 row only. The Sr_No column in the Desired output is now plain sequence number generation after the detected objects from  1 frame have been written in the row. You can also exclude the Sr No column (if that creates the confusion) from the Desired Output for a while and help me solve the actual problem

Comment: It's not the just a confusion, the `Sr_No` and `File_Name` columns are inconsistent when compared to the input

Comment: @Ashargin Brother u can skip the Sr_No part for now and the File_name column contains the name of the frame. Hence it changes after every row

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for.

```
def group_concat_rows(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('File_Name').apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.apply(str))))
    return grouped.drop('File_Name', axis=1)
```

This is really not a beautiful way to write it but I couldn't find something more elegant.

Example :

```
df
                File_Name Object_Detected  Probability
Sr_No                                                 
1      tiger_23sec_f0.jpg           tiger     0.997508
2      tiger_23sec_f0.jpg         vehicle     0.902771
1      tiger_23sec_f1.jpg           tiger     0.996490
2      tiger_23sec_f1.jpg         vehicle     0.910558

group_concat_rows(df)
                   Object_Detected           Probability
File_Name                                               
tiger_23sec_f0.jpg   tiger,vehicle  0.9975079,0.90277094
tiger_23sec_f1.jpg   tiger,vehicle   0.9964898,0.9105579
```

I have supposed that your key is `File_Name` and I have ignored `Sr_No` because those two columns are inconsistent from your output to your input so you might want to clarify your question if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ignoring the Sr_No is fine as of now. Just wanted to clarify 1 thing. Your object named df is the same which is named as csv_file in my script above?

Comment: No, df is your current output. This is a function to be applied at the end, so that rows are "concatenated". I think it's clear, I showed `df` and `group_concat_rows(df)` so you can see what the function does.